# Rails 4, Simple Form, accepts_nested_attributes_for, Dropzone image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form, has-many, dropzone.js

Is there a way with a has_many association (User --> Uploads) to work with a nested form? I have the strong params working fine. Users can have 5 images uploaded. I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for in the model and uploading is working, but there are some gotchas.

But for example when I try to edit the User, and build only new images using:

```
(5 - @user.uploads.count).times { @user.uploads.build }
```

...it builds 5 upload entries within the nested form, no matter what. Form section looks like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :uploads do |i| %>
      <hr>
      <% user.uploads.each do |upload| %>
        <% if upload.image? %>
          <%= image_tag(upload.image.url(:medium), class: 'img-rounded').html_safe %>
          <br>
          <%= i.input :_destroy, as: :boolean,
                              label: false,
                       inline_label: 'Remove picture',
                       wrapper_html: { class: 'text-center' } %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

        <%= i.file_field :image %>
        <h4>or</h4>
        <%= i.input :image_remote_url, label: 'Enter an image URL' %>
    <% end %>
```

Previously I had images uploading via a Dropzone ajax form, but as a nested resource and URL to a distinct Uploads controller. Now I have to make the uploads on the same form as the User profile edit. Ideally I would like to use a Dropzone on the profile edit page, but that seems even worse.

If anyone has tips on how to handle multiple file uploads (new / create AND edit / update actions), where I can have a limit of 5 uploads, I'd love to hear it. Also, implementation of multiple nested uploads via an embedded Dropzone would be even better if possible.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use Dropzone with nested forms? I am facing a similar problem.